# How can I use a local variable to use a method from another class in BlueJ?

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, local

Basically I have two classes Country and City. In city I have a method called getSize. I want to use this method in the Country class so I tried using this:

```
City c = City.getSize();
```

To store the method as a local variable but I either get an error about incompatible types or static methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this if your method `getSize` is not static:

```
City c = new City();
int size = c.getSize(); // use the returned value (assuming it is returning an integer)
```

And if the method is static then you can directly use it with the class name:

```
int size = City.getSize();
```

But I think you require first one as all city instance will have different size.

For the question : `To store the method as a local variable`

Answer : You cannot do such thing in java. You should first create an instance of the class and then you can call the method using that instance any number of time you want.

Comment: Despite you saying it had to be static the first method worked anyway. In the end I used int size = city.getSize(); to reference the getSize method in the variable size. Thanks very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

can you show the error?

And why don't you create

```
City c = new City(); 
int size = c.getSize();
```

Comment: I dont really understand? I thought you could create a local variable that you could use as a reference to another Class. In a previous one i did I wanted to get the highest bid from a class called bid so i used this

Comment: I dont really understand? I thought you could create a local variable that you could use as a reference to another Class. In a previous one i did I wanted to see which lots has been bidded on. To do this i used a for loop to iterate over an ArrayList and then I used a line that reads Bid bid = lot.getHighestBid to access a method in the Lot class so that bid was the new variable that represented the highest bid. I'm quite confused? Would it be worth uploading the code?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean - if it is important for you, you can upload the code.